# Is it possible to perform functions during LOAD DATA INFILE without creating a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, etl

I have two columns, q1 and q2, that I'd like to sum together and put in the destination column, q.

The way I do it now, I put the data in an intermediate table, then sum during loading, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it during extraction instead?

Here's my script:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\temp\foo.csv'
    INTO TABLE new_foo
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (q1,q1)

INSERT INTO foo (q) SELECT q1+q2 AS q
FROM foo_temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\temp\foo.csv'
    INTO TABLE `foo`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@`q1`, @`q2`)
    SET `q` = @`q1` + @`q2`;
```